# Weak * convergent vs strongly convergent.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, weak-convergence

I read in Kreyszig the following definitions.

$\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $X,Y$ normed spaces and $T_n:X \rightarrow Y$ a sequence of bounded linear operators. We say that $T_n$ converges strongly to $T:X\rightarrow Y$ if

$$ \Vert T_n(x)- T(x) \Vert \to 0 , \forall x\in X $$

$\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $X$ a normed space and $f_n \in X'$ a sequence. We say that $f_n$ converges weakly * if exists $f\in X'$ such that

$$ \vert f_n(x) - f(x) \vert \to 0, \forall x\in X $$

In the first case, $T$ may be unbounded if $X$ is not complete. Put $Y=\mathbb{R}$ the definitions are almost the same except for the fact that in the second they tell that $f$ has to be continuous and in the first not.

My doubt comes because the author comments that in the case of working with linear functionals the first definition coincides with the second, but I think they are not the same.

See pag. 266 of Kreyszig: Introductory Functional Analysis with applications.

Comment: I don't see the comment in Kreyszig? One is weak*-convergence and the other is strong operator convergence so I don't see the relation between them.

Comment: Taken from page 266 before definition 4.9.4: Linear functions are linear operators ... so that (1),(2) and (3) apply immediately. However (2) and (3) now become equivalent, for the following reason ... The two remaining concepts are called $\textbf{strong and weak* convergence}$. Notice that (2) is the definition of strongly convergence of operators.

Comment: (3) is $|f(T_nx)- f(Tx)| \to 0, \forall f\in Y^*, x\in X$? This is not what you wrote.

Comment: Note that if $T$ is linear functional, then it maps $T:X\to \mathbb{R}$ and thus $Tx\in \mathbb{R}$ which is one-dimensional. Now apply the Theorem 4.8-4.

Comment: @ureui Yes, that is the definition of (3) but I did not write it because I only wanted to compare (2). Yes that argument serves to prove that 2 and 3 are equivalent. But my question is not that, my question is that if they are equivalent to weak * convergence.

Comment: Why don't you think they are equivalent? We have that $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^*$.

Comment: Because in (2) the limit $T$ is not necessarily continuous and in the definition of weak * convergence the limit is in $X'$ so is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The two definitions are not equivalent when $Y=\mathbb C$ and $X$ is not complete.  Let $X$ be the space of trigonometric polynomials on $[0,2\pi]$ with the $L^2$-norm, and let $f_n:X\to\mathbb C$ be defined by linear extension of
$$f_n(e^{ikx})=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \text{if }|k|\leq n,\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.$$
Then the sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $X^*$ converges strongly to an unbounded functional, hence cannot converge weak$^*$ to a bounded functional.